# Unable to set password for root@localhost in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have tried various options I got from Google but unable to set password for `root`. I can login without any password, but the Java drivers require a password, so I have to set it.

In my last attempt, I tried following command in the MySQL console:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost=PASSWORD('abc123');
```

But I got following error:

```
ERROR 1133 <42000>: Can't find any matching row in the user table
```

Comment: what user are you logged in as?  root?

Comment: yes i am logged in as root but with no password. 1 more thing i forgot i have installed wamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter the following lines in your terminal.

Stop the MySQL Server.

> sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop

Start the mysqld configuration. (in safe mode)

> ```
> sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
> ```

Login to MySQL as root.

```
mysql -u root mysql
```

Replace YOURNEWPASSWORD with your new password!

```
UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('YOURNEWPASSWORD') WHERE User='root'; 
FLUSH PRIVILEGES; 
exit;
```

> sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start

***REFERENCES :***

http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset

Comment: Thanks! Updating the `mysql`.`user` table directly worked for me, while `SET PASSWORD FOR..` failed not being able to find  a matching row.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the user `root` for `localhost` does not exists. Adding this account can be done by:

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'abc123';
```

Comment: thanks, but this command resulted in another error ACCESS DENIED: You need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privileges for this operation.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, each user is uniquely identified by both the username and the host, meaning that `root@localhost` is not the same user as `root@127.0.0.1` or `root@%` (for example). It could be that you don't have the `root@localhost` user that you're trying to set the password for.

Double-check which users you actually have in the `mysql.user` table:

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'root';
```

If you want create the missing user, use these statements instead:

```
CREATE USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'abc123';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@localhost;
```